# Is GitHub adequate for purposes of giving a manuscript a timestamp to protect against plagiarism?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

I wrote a paper that I want to put on my webpage, but that I don't want to publish anywhere.  I think that I need a timestamp on it, in case someone decides to plagiarize it.  Is GitHub adequate for this?

Comment: Did you consider arXiv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/712/how-to-prevent-plagiarism-of-my-papers  http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23367/how-can-i-time-stamp-my-data-without-publishing-it  or http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/435/is-it-advisable-to-put-entire-source-of-my-thesis-up-on-github/442#442

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov - One must be invited to arXiv, and if I want to change the paper later, it is my understanding that I cannot do that with arXiv (I must instead upload a new version, and keep the old one as well.)

Comment: If I am not very much mistaken, you can access older versions on ArXiv (see for example [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0703762v1)). Of course you do not want to constantly revise your paper this way. As for the invitation, if you know other people who have published in your field, there is a high chance that one of them can invite (endorse) you, as you become an endorser quite quickly.

Comment: It is not difficult at all to be endorsed on arXiv, if you know people in your field. You're right that arXiv provides full version control with all timestamps - in the same way as public github repo does.

Comment: @horsehair Is your aim to be able to edit in case you spot mistakes, or rather - you aim is to have continuous development?

Comment: I don't know anyone in my field.  My aim is to have a timestamp that others will believe, in the case that someone claims to have produced my work themselves.  I will only make small changes to the document from now on.

Comment: @Dmitry , I would say ArXiv does limited version control.  (For example, you can't remove versions.)  For the basic purpose of providing an independent timestamp, ArXiv and Github suffice.  Legally, a notary is better.

Comment: Remember that neither GitHub nor ArXiv can guarantee to still be in business when you need that evidence. If you care enough to want a clear timestamp, getting it notarized is a fairly cheap investment. Especially if someone in your school's staff is a notary (fairly common) and offers discount services to colleagues (also fairly common).

Comment: The proposed duplicate does *not* seem like a duplicate, because it is about data, not a paper.

Comment: _I don't know anyone in my field._ — Then you have a _much_ more serious problem than time-stamping your work!!

Comment: @JeffE - I just finished my Master's, and I generally work in a different field.  I know my adviser, but he doesn't use arXiv.  Am I expected to know more people?

Comment: Then you *do* know someone (even if he's not directly in your field)! Have you asked your advisor?

Comment: @ChristianClason - Read the comment again please.  He doesn't use arXiv

Comment: Yes, but he might know other ways to achieve what you want (certified self-publication) besides arXiv; for example, he could ask your library to publish your paper as a technical report in their digital repository, if such a thing exists.

Comment: Why do you want to 'put the paper on your webpage', but not 'publish'? If you believe there is a chance of plagiarism, then your paper should be interesting enough to send to a journal, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's be scientists (It was fun to try out):
below is a small repository, where I first tried 'lol' to have a timestamp in the future ... doesn't work; but at least in 'history' I could backdate (bit unlikely that I authored s.th. in git 1980 ;-).

But at least the day that I pushed is set by github.com. In total, though, I wouldn't trust this scheme. ``I forgot to push but look at the authored date, I totally solved it years ago''.

Jul 15, 2014

history
2b5d4208aa Browse code 
choener authored on Jan 1, 1980

lol
fc2a68a571 Browse code 
choener authored just now

https://github.com/choener/lol/commits/master

Comment: For plagiarism protection git timestamps may be useless, but exposing code publicly (public awareness, possible forks, Wayback Machine) GitHub may serve its role (vide there was a post that the best way to protect against plagiarism is to sent a draft to _many_ scientists).

Comment: Absolutely! I only considered the technical 'timestamp' aspect. I prefer to have all my libraries on github and all my preprints on my webpage + preprint servers. (And the community is small enough that it doesn't matter for me)

Answer (score 1):

Poor man's copyright protection can be done by sending a copy of the work to yourself by registered mail. The timestamp is provided by the federal government and as long as the envelope remains sealed, it is proof of creation on or before that date. Of course, I would also get a notarized or authenticated document as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for copyright, so of dubious legal value: http://www.snopes.com/legal/postmark.asp

Comment: Unless you are planning on suing somebody for publishing your idea, I don't see why the law has much to do with this.

Comment: It's just to timestamp when you had written some idea in that form. I made no claims about legal value for a lawsuit. Also, the Snopes link only applies to USA and UK.

Comment: Technically, this only proves existence of the *envelope*  on or before that date (the postmark is not tamper proof); as long as you have possession of the sealed envelope, I don't see how this would convince anyone who wouldn't already take your word for it. Hence the  service of a notary. (But if you visit France, the [Soleau envelope](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enveloppe_Soleau) is a poor man's notary.)